# Importing used car from Italy to another EU country

Tags: italy, vehicle-registration

This question is in reference to this [post](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9711/importing-used-car-from-italy-how-to-get-export-plates).

> If the car is still registered in the previous owner's name, drive it across the border with that registration and re-register it upon arrival. Some owners may be reluctant to do this, though, as it would entail various risks for them.

Do you know, if this still a legal practice? Could I run into issues with Italian Police? I am planning to do this in a few days.

Reading [this](https://www.aci.it/i-servizi/guide-utili/guida-pratiche-auto/esportazione.html) (from the header "Veicoli esportati dal 1° gennaio 2020 e già reimmatricolati all’estero ma non ancora radiati dall’ANV e dal PRA") makes me think it would be a legal practice, but it is not very straight-forward.

Would have signed bill of sale (vehicle sales agreement) & seller's registration documents & insurance documents with me.

Comment: Getting a transfer license plate is still the best way of insuring that all the paperwork has be done correctly.

Comment: Sure, but we ran into a weird bureaucracy caused problem with this.

I don't want to pay upfront to a random stranger only on a promise and he does not want to start export procedure in case we won't close a deal, since it would cost him a lot of time and money to register the car again. If we could get the plates immediately from Italian PRA, like in many other EU countries, instead of waiting for weeks, there would be no such issue.